# How to push an html element to right, as the previous element grows in width dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have two input `textbox` that grows dynamically based on the size of the input. In between that there is a small text. The problem is that when the `textbox` grows in width, it overlaps the text next to it.

I am looking for an `HTML/CSS` styling that lets me push the text to right side as the `textbox` grows in width.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Adding some of my code.

```css
.dynamic-push {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row dynamic-push">
  <div class="two columns dynamic-push ">
    <input id="contact-position" class="dynamic-push" value="" type="text" placeholder="Position" data-bind="value: Person().Position, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', afterRender: $('#contact-position').autosizeInput()" /> at
    <input id="contact-company" value="" type="text" placeholder="Company" data-bind="value: Person().Company, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', afterRender: $('#contact-company').autosizeInput()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

There are knockout elements and I have used jquery `autosize.input.js` plugin to increase the width of the input text box dynamically.

Now the 'at' between the two input textboxes is being overlapped by the first `textbox` as it grows.
Hope you can figure out what is wrong here. If you need any other `CSS` codes, I'll share those too

Comment: Can you post some code or an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Shouldn't placing the div underneath or somewhere else a better option in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Why not simple float them left within a container:

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LxByQ/)**</kbd>

(demo contains animation enlarging the textbox)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input><div>Box 1</div<div>Box 2</div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > input,
div > div {
    float:left;
}
```

(of course exchange div with a proper class).

**Update**

Thanks to OP for providing more code.

However, as you can see in this modified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LxByQ/2/

the problem is not at DOM level as the boxes pushes and moves as expected.

The problem is most likely in the autosizeInput function which deals with the chars and so forth. The delay can be caused by how it handles this. As the code for it isn't shown it's hard to locate exact reason but this is where you want to look in first instance.

Comment: I tried your method. Now the issue is that the elements do get pushed, but at different speed. The second div tag moves slower than the first input tag. And so it still overlaps the second div tag after a while. I have used the jquery autosize.input plugin to get dynamic width for my textbox.

Comment: @user2597617 it's a little bit hard to dissect as you are not showing any code/context. There could by (very likely) other factors that influences. Please show some of the code you are working with in your question. That will make it a bit easier for us to pin-point the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how that automatic resize function handles it. If it adjusts the width of the first input field, you can try flexbox:

```
<div class="row dynamic-push">
  <div class="two columns dynamic-push mylittleflexcontainer">
    <input id="contact-position" class="dynamic-push" value="" type="text" placeholder="Position" data-bind="value: Person().Position, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', afterRender: $('#contact-position').autosizeInput()" />
    <span> at</span>
    <input id="contact-company" value="" type="text" placeholder="Company" data-bind="value: Person().Company, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', afterRender: $('#contact-company').autosizeInput()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.mylittleflexcontainer {
   display: flex;
}
.mylittleflexcontainer:first-child {
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```